# Varagrs, Array and parameter list

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions

I have searched the forum but I am still unable to understand the following differences:

```
    1) void sum(5,5,5,6,7,8,9,3,5,3,2,3,6){}
    2) void sum(int[] i){}
    3) void sum(int... i){}
```

And if 3) can be treated as array then what about 1)?

Comment: 1) Its invalid,you cant define method like this 2) int array as paramter 3) you can pass many int variables it will be resolve at dynamic time

Comment: 1) Fixed no. of parameters, each being an `int/short`. 2) Single parameter, and that is an `int[]`. 3) Variable no. of parameters, each being an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

void `sum(5,5,5,6,7,8,9,3,5,3,2,3,6){}` won't even compile because it is not a valid method declaration

> A method parameter list in parenthesis should be a comma-delimited list of input parameters, preceded by their data types, enclosed by parentheses.

2 & 3 are basically the same thing except if you will call the method `sum(5,5,5);` it won't resolve to method `void sum(int[] a ){}` because this method is expecting an `int array` as an calle method argument whereas `void sum(int... a){}` will work fine as it is expecting variable number of `int` type arguments in method call.

Answer (score 0):

2 and 3 are basically the same thing. 3 is more elegant because you dont have to create the array before calling the method. Java does that for you.

1 is useful if the number of arguments are never going to change.

Comment: @Youngistan - I really doubt that the OP meant those to be compilable. It was just used for explanation purposes, AFAICT.

Comment: Agreed. Actually I assumed by all those random integers, he meant different parameters.